# When the screen goes black, all apps crash

Tags: 17.10, crash, lock-screen

I am used to my screen turning off after a couple of minutes of inactivity. If I move the mouse or use the keyboard, I expect either to see the lock screen or preferably to be taken directly back to all my open apps.

Since doing a fresh install of 17.10, often (but not all the time), when the screen goes black, upon reactivating all apps are closed. Firefox then says it hasn't closed properly and offers to restore tabs, LibreOffice offers to restore documents, etc, so it does not seem like a clean shut down either.

How can I find out what's causing this and fix it? Thanks.

In my settings, screen lock is turned off and automatic suspend is disabled.